# How to install packages in Anaconda environment in VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I am running my code in VScode, my python interpreter being Anconda3\python.exe . When running the following code : -

```
from Ipython import display
```

I encounter the following error in the python terminal :

```
PS C:\Users\Clover\Desktop\Speech Recognition> C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/Clover/Desktop/Speech Recognition/ml_code_first.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Clover/Desktop/Speech Recognition/ml_code_first.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Ipython import display
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Ipython'
```

I've tried to install it on the conda terminal using :

```
pip install ipython
```

and it shows that requirement already satisfied which means the package is installed but why is this package not detected in VScode?

Answer (score 0):

At least there is the warning from the conda developers: Never mix conda-forge installs and pip installs. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is `conda` instead of `venv`:

Use `conda install <<your libary name>>>`

I also had the same issues over time!